# Different behavior of new() constructor

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to understand a reason for the different results between the usage of the `new()` constructor in SystemVerilog.

I understood that if once the constructor allocates the memory into the object by `new()`, then I can use it in a class. I don't need it anymore after constructed by `new()`. But, I can't understand the result between commented them out and not commented out as below:

```
typedef enum {GOOD, BAD_ERR1, BAD_ERR2} pkt_type;

class driver;
  pkt_type pkt;
  
  task pkt_sender;
    std::randomize(pkt) with {pkt == GOOD;};
    modify_pkt;
  endtask
  
  virtual task modify_pkt; // callback method
   // $display("Good !! modify_pkt");
  endtask
endclass

// Error introduction via err_driver class where callback method modify_pkt is implemented.
class err_driver extends driver;
  task modify_pkt;
    $display("Injecting error pkt");
    std::randomize(pkt) with {pkt inside {BAD_ERR1, BAD_ERR2};};
  endtask
endclass

class env;
  bit inject_err;
  driver drv;
  err_driver drv_err;
  
  function new();
    drv = new();
    drv_err = new();
  endfunction
  
  task execute;
    if(inject_err) drv = drv_err;
    // Sending a packet
    drv.pkt_sender();
    $display("Sending packet = %s", drv.pkt.name());
  endtask
endclass

module callback_example();
  env env_o;
  initial begin
    // Sending GOOD packet
    env_o = new();
    env_o.inject_err = 0;
    repeat(3) env_o.execute;
    
    // Injecting an error
    //env_o = new(); //Test for new()
    env_o.inject_err = 1;
    repeat(3) env_o.execute;
    
    // Sending GOOD packet
    //env_o = new(); //Test for new()
    env_o.inject_err = 0;
    repeat(3) env_o.execute;
  end
endmodule
```

If the 2nd and 3rd `env_o = new();` statements are commented out, then I expected results below:

```
Sending packet = GOOD
Sending packet = GOOD
Sending packet = GOOD
Injecting error pkt
Sending packet = BAD_ERR1
Injecting error pkt
Sending packet = BAD_ERR1
Injecting error pkt
Sending packet = BAD_ERR1
Sending packet = GOOD
Sending packet = GOOD
Sending packet = GOOD
```

But, I get these unexpected result:

```
Sending packet = GOOD
Sending packet = GOOD
Sending packet = GOOD
Injecting error pkt
Sending packet = BAD_ERR1
Injecting error pkt
Sending packet = BAD_ERR1
Injecting error pkt
Sending packet = BAD_ERR1
Injecting error pkt
Sending packet = BAD_ERR2
Injecting error pkt
Sending packet = BAD_ERR2
Injecting error pkt
Sending packet = BAD_ERR1
```

I thought that even if I commented them out, then the result of `new()` constructor is the same in SystemVerilog. But, it is not the same. Could you guide me why the results are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `new` on the `env_o` handle, it calls the  `new` function in the `env` class.  This constructs two *different* objects: `drv` and `drv_err`.

When you execute:

```
env_o.inject_err = 1;
repeat(3) env_o.execute;
```

the 1st time `execute` is called, it sets the `drv` object to be *the same as* `drv_err`.  `drv` is permanently set to be `drv_err`.  This is why you keep getting `BAD` instead of `GOOD`.

The way to make `drv` and `drv_err` different from each other again is to call `env_o.new` again.